# ES6 Big arrow notation function giving SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, ecmascript-6

I'm trying my hand on ES6's way to make new functions.

I'm trying to golf a function.

This is what I have so far:

```
F=>(s){/[^aeiou]{3}|[jqxz]/.test(s)};
```

**BUT** this is returning a cryptic error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

If I try without braces:

```
F=>(s)/[^aeiou]{3}|[jqxz]/.test(s);
```

I get the folowing error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '^'
```

The regex works fine on it's own.

You can try it yourself.

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

---

I've tested this on the latest Firefox version (currently, version 35.0.1).

I used it straight into the console: no Firebug on this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```js
var F = s => /[^aeiou]{3}|[jqxz]/.test(s);
```

That creates an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) which receives an argument `s` and returns `/[^aeiou]{3}|[jqxz]/.test(s)`.

And that function is assigned to the variable `F`.

---

Note that you could also use a not much longer alternative which works in ES5 and should perform better because it won't recreate the regex object at each call.

```js
var F = /(?:)/.test.bind(/[^aeiou]{3}|[jqxz]/);
```

Comment: Holy god! That was fast! o.O And no downvotes yet, which is also good for me. Sorry my stupidity. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: About the shorter one... I have a requirement to write a function that returns `true` or `false`. Since ES6 shortened **a lot** the way you create a function, I used it. The idea is to trim it down to the bare minimum.